# SQL Parent Child query - relation is defined in two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree

I know that there are similar questions here but I couldn't find my particular situation in them, so I want to ask you and I hope that you will advise me on how it's better to do it.

I have this <kbd>[`SQL Fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/443b8/14)</kbd>.
I have two tables:

```
CATEGORIES (ID, 
             NAME, 
             PARENT_ID, 
             SORT_ORDER)
```

And

```
CATEGORY_ITEMS (ID,
                 NAME, 
                 CATEGORY_ID, 
                 SORT_ORDER)
```

These two tables are somehow the resume of my real database schema (I don't have the possibility to change it). In my real database schema, these categories can define sets that are valid based on certain datetime values. 
I would like to know if it is possible to return results like below with one query.

```
|           NAME    | 
|-------------------|
|Category 1         |   
|Item 1 Category 1  |  
|Item 2 Category 1  |   
|Category 1.1       | 
|Item 1 Category 1.1|    
|Item 2 Category 1.1|      
|Category 1.2       |      
| Category 1.2.1    |       
|     Category 2    |   
|Item 1 Category 2  |   
|Item 2 Category 2  |    
|   Category 2.1    |       
|   Category 2.2    |        
|     Category 3    |    
|   Category 3.1    |        
|   Category 3.2    |
```

In the SQL Fiddle you can see my work until now. I think that I can obtain what I want by getting the tree structure from `CATEGORIES` into a cursor and for each record I should get it's records from `CATEGORY_ITEMS`, but I was wondering if there is a possibility to do it without a cursor.
I admit that I am not to good at SQL but I am trying to be better so that's why I am asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE(ID, NAME, PARENT_ID, SORT_ORDER, [Level], ord)  AS (
    SELECT c.ID, CONVERT(nvarchar(100), c.NAME), 
        c.PARENT_ID, c.SORT_ORDER, 1 [level], 
        CONVERT(nvarchar(255), RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(nvarchar(255), c.ID), 4)) AS ord
    FROM CATEGORIES c
    WHERE c.PARENT_ID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.ID, CONVERT(nvarchar(100), REPLICATE('  ', [Level]) + c.NAME), 
        c.PARENT_ID, c.SORT_ORDER, CTE.[Level] + 1, 
        CONVERT(nvarchar(255),RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(nvarchar(255), CTE.ID), 4) + RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(nvarchar(255), c.ID), 4)) AS ord
    FROM CATEGORIES c
        JOIN CTE ON c.PARENT_ID = CTE.ID
    WHERE c.PARENT_ID IS NOT NULL)
SELECT NAME
FROM (
    SELECT NAME, ord, 1 As ord2
    FROM CTE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ci.NAME, c.ord, 2 + ci.SORT_ORDER
    FROM CATEGORY_ITEMS ci 
    JOIN CTE c ON ci.CATEGORY_ID = c.ID) dt
ORDER BY ord, ord2
```

For this:

```
NAME
Category 1
Item 1 Category 1
Item 2 Category 1
  Category 1.1
Item 1 Category 1.1
Item 2 Category 1.1
  Category 1.2
    Category 1.2.1
Category 2
Item 1 Category 2
Item 2 Category 2
  Category 2.1
  Category 2.2
Category 3
  Category 3.1
  Category 3.2
```